# YA sci-fi book about a servant family living on the estate of a noble family with a magical bloodline

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I hope one you lovely people might be able to help me remember a book title I’ve forgotten, as I really want to re-read it. I read it a few years ago and was sure I read it on Kindle Unlimited but can’t find it on my KU read list, I don’t think its earlier than 2010 or thereabouts. I have tried everything I can think of but no luck so far.

All I can remember is that the main characters are a pretty normal family,  but they have to do so many years Labour Service, and the majority of the family end up on the estate of this high ranking family, and they have some sort of bloodline magic and only their family can open the gates to the estate.

The servant family’s son gets separated and sent to a factory town. The father is a chauffeur, I think, and one of the daughters ends up being a babysitter to the illegitimate child of one of the noble family. There is some crazy relation who keeps a man as a half human/dog hybrid, and the daughter helps him escape and he goes berserk, I think.